# I can't say more, I really can't

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Under Sahara, delicious tuber
Greek cheese, asian sword way
Translucent dead, getting older
Communication device, outdoor shelter
Heawy iron block, Neeson's name
Shining coating, exists forever
Prime prime, standing infinity
Stack gone rong, carbon-based

Comment: Heawy instead of Heavy, gone rong, instead of gone wrong. Typos or intended?

Comment: Definitely not typos ;)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Thanks to all partial answers and @Riley's comment:

*Under Sahara, delicious tuber*

> SAHEL, POTATO
>  The Sahel is a region south of the Sahara. Thanks @bandrade.

*Greek cheese, asian sword way*

> FETA, KENDO
>  Kendo is literally "the way of the sword" in japanese. Thanks to @Teo, and to the OP for the explanation.

*Translucent dead, getting older*

> GHOST, AGEING
>  Thanks to @Teo.

*Communication device, outdoor shelter*

> PHONE, TENT
>  Thanks to @Rand al'Thor for PHONE and to @Daniel Baliki for TENT

*Heawy iron block, Neeson's name*

> ANWIL, LIAM
>  Thanks to @Teo for ANWIL and to @Rand al'Thor for LIAM.

*Shining coating, exists forever*

> LUSTRE, ETERNAL
>  Thanks to @DanielBaliki for ETERNAL.

*Prime prime, standing infinity*

> 2, 8
>  2 is the first ("prime") prime. 8 is $\infty$ on end. Thanks to @Rand al'Thor.

*Stack gone rong, carbon-based*

> OVERFLO, ORGANIC
>  Thanks to @Teo

**Everything put together:**

> SA**HEL P**OTATO
>  FE**TA KEN**DO
>  G**HOST AGE**ING
>  PH**ONE TEN**T
>  AN**WIL LIAM**
>  LU**STRE ET**ERNAL
>  **2 8**
>  OVER**FLO OR**GANIC

We get the sentence:

> Help taken hostage 110 William Street 28 floor

**Explanation**

> StackExchange has an office at 110 William Street on the 28th floor!

Comment: Thank you! Seing how clever this community is for solving this so quickly, they freed me in fear of retaliation! Hopefully they will learn from their mistake...

Comment: @barto Very nice, I was expecting the form to change up and not be entirely the same for the others.

Comment: @theREALyumdub Thanks! I'm new to the site and the answers here are the only I've seen; I'll add more details too.

Answer (score 17):

**Partial answer**

*Under Sahara, delicious tuber*

> Something, POTATO?

*Greek cheese, asian sword way*

> FETA, KENDO (thanks @Teo). There are many types of both Greek cheese and Asian sword, but this makes sense for the reason pointed out by @ManyPinkHats.

*Translucent dead, getting older*

> GHOST, AGEING (thanks @Teo).

*Communication device, outdoor shelter*

> PHONE, something (e.g. could be SHED or HUT).

*Heawy iron block, Neeson's name*

> ANWIL (thanks @Teo), LIAM.

*Shining coating, exists forever*

> POLISH (thanks @DanielBaliki), DIAMOND?

*Prime prime, standing infinity*

> TWO (first prime), EIGHT ($\infty$ on end)

*Stack gone rong, carbon-based*

> OVERFLO, ORGANIC (thanks @Teo).

Let's put all that together (bold for ones I'm pretty sure about):

> ??? POTATO
>  **FETA KENDO**
>  **GHOST AGEING**
>  PHONE HUT
>  **ANWIL LIAM**
>  POLISH DIAMOND
>  **TWO EIGHT**
>  **OVERFLO ORGANIC**

Now look at what's popping out of the 5th and some other lines:

> ???, TAKEN, HOSTAGE, ???, WILLIAM, ???, WOE, FLOOR

Comment: Based on @Teo's answer, I see some other things that might be popping: ROT13(Vs gur frpbaq yvar vf SRGN XRAQB, gung pbagnvaf GNXRA. Vs gur guveq yvar vf TUBFG NTRVAT, gung pbagnvaf UBFGNTR. Obgu whzc bhg ng zr fvapr Yvnz Arrfba vf rkcyvpvgyl ersreraprq nyernql.) (EDIT: This actually works with the title, thematically, I think.)

Comment: You're absolutely on the right track, please persevere (please...)! Also, as for the time I write this, 2 of your five "unsure" (not bold) words are correct.

Comment: @Keelhaul Given the method, LIFE is clearly not correct, and PHONE and HUT can't both be correct. Thanks for the mini [tag:logical-deduction] puzzle :-P

Comment: ROT13: Vs gur ynfg jbeq jrer "betnavp", vg jbhyq fcryy "sybbe"...

Comment: ROT 13: vs jr gnxr gur ynfg gjb yrggref bs gur 4gu Pyhr(sbe cubar naq furq), jr trg arrq(juvpu fbhaqf cynhfvoyr gurzngvpnyyl). Naq sybbe frrzf gb svg orggre jvgu gur Crahygvzngr pyhr nf n jubyr engure guna jbr.

Comment: I think the second to last line may be indicating that rot13(Ur vf gnxra ubfgntr ba gur gjragl rvtugu sybbe bs n ohvyqvat)

Comment: Here are a couple of thoughts, but I can't make them fit into the overall puzzle:    Line 4 - rot13(CUBAR + LHEG = UBARL), Line 6 - rot13(TYBFF + RAQHEVAT = FRAQ)

Answer (score 11):

It's not much, but I hope it helps:

*Under Sahara, delicious tuber*

> Sa**hel** (transition area, to the South of the Sahara), **P**otato =>  **HELP**

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Rand al'Thor's reasoning:

Asian sword way

> A katana is a sword, not a sword *way*. I was thinking of **BUSHIDO**. Or **KENDO**, or **IAIDO**... there are lots of possibilities.

Getting older

> Aging?

Heawy iron block

> **ANWIL**!

Carbon-based

> Could be organic?

Comment: Re heawy iron block - good one!!

Comment: Which, when written before the other word in that row, forms...

Comment: Also, I've edited the first box.

Comment: Note that rot13(Xraqb vf yvgrenyyl "gur jnl bs gur fjbeq" va wncnarfr)

Answer (score 7):

I'm not entirely sure for most of these, but here are my partial answers:

Under Sahara, delicious tuber

> Water, ???

Greek cheese, asian sword way

> Feta, Kendo

Translucent dead, getting older

> Ghost, Aging

Communication device, outdoor shelter

> Radio, Tent

Heawy iron block, Neeson's name

> Anwil, Liam

Shining coating, exists forever

> Polish, Eternal

Prime prime, standing infinity

> Two, Eight

Stack gone rong, carbon-based

> Hayire, Life

Comment: Some mistakes, but you got 2 words @RandAl'Thor hasn't got !